# How to detect when `canvas.captureStream()` is not supported?

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, mobile-safari

[It is known that iOS Safari does not support](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181663) `canvas.captureStream()` to (e.g.) pipe its content into a video element, see [this demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-video/) not working in iOS Safari.

However, `canvas.captureStream()` is a valid function in iOS Safari, and correctly returns a `CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack`, it just doesn't function as intended. In order to detect browsers that don't support `canvas.captureStream`, it would have been easy to do a test `typeof canvas.captureStream === 'function'`, but at least for iOS Safari, we can't rely on that. Neither can we rely on the type of the returned value.

How do I write JavaScript that detects whether the current browser effectively supports `canvas.captureStream()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No iOS to test it here, but according to the comments on the issue you linked to, `captureStream()` actually works, what doesn't is the HTMLVideoElement's reading of this MediaStream. So that's what you actually want to test.

According to the messages there, the video doesn't even *fail* to load the video (i.e the metadata are correctly set and I don't expect events like `error` to fire, though if it does, then it's quite simple to test: check if a video is able to play such a MediaStream.

```js
function testReadingOfCanvasCapturedStream() {
  // first check the DOM API is available
  if( !testSupportOfCanvasCapureStream() ) {
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }
  // create a test canvas
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  // we need to init a context on the canvas
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const stream = canvas.captureStream();
  const vid = document.createElement("video");
  vid.muted = true;
  vid.playsInline = true;
  vid.srcObject = stream;
  let supports = false;

  // Safari needs we draw on the canvas
  // asynchronously after we requested the MediaStream
  setTimeout(() => ctx.fillRect(0,0,5,5));

  // if it failed, .play() would be enough
  // but according to the comments on the issue, it isn't
  return vid.play()
    .then(() => supports = true)
    .finally(() => {
      // clean
      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      return supports;
    });
}
function testSupportOfCanvasCapureStream() {
  return "function" === typeof HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.captureStream;
}
testReadingOfCanvasCapturedStream()
  .then(supports => console.log(supports));
```

But if the video is able to play, but no images is painted, then we have to go a bit deeper and check what has been painted on the video. To do this, we'll draw some color on the canvas, wait for the video to have loaded and draw it back on the canvas before checking the color of the frame on the canvas:

```js
async function testReadingOfCanvasCapturedStream() {
  // first check the DOM API is available
  if( !testSupportOfCanvasCapureStream() ) {
    return false;
  }
  // create a test canvas
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  // we need to init a context on the canvas
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const stream = canvas.captureStream();
  const clean = () => stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  const vid = document.createElement("video");
  vid.muted = true;
  vid.srcObject = stream;

  // Safari needs we draw on the canvas
  // asynchronously after we requested the MediaStream
  setTimeout(() => {
    // we draw in a well knwown color
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);
  });

  try {
    await vid.play();
  }
  catch(e) {
    // failed to load, no need to go deeper
    // it's not supported
    clean();
    return false; 
  }
  // here we should have our canvas painted on the video
  // let's keep this image on the video
  await vid.pause();

  // now draw it back on the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150);
  ctx.drawImage(vid,0,0);
  const pixel_data = ctx.getImageData(5,5,1,1).data;
  const red_channel = pixel_data[0];

  clean();

  return red_channel > 0; // it has red
}
function testSupportOfCanvasCapureStream() {
  return "function" === typeof HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.captureStream;
}

testReadingOfCanvasCapturedStream()
  .then(supports => console.log(supports));
```

Comment: Tested on iOS and confirmed that it logs "false". Thank you for an insight answer!

Comment: @AndréStaltz does it work for both snippets or only the second one?

Comment: Only the second one, the first one doesn't log anything

Comment: Interesting, I originally opened this question with iOS Safari in mind, but now I realize that Safari 14 (macOS) has issues, it doesn't log anything for the second snippet!

Comment: @AndréStaltz thanks for the heads up. Definitely did work with the previous version. Apparently they don't like drawing videos with a stopped stream on canvas anymore.